# Reliance on default encoding in sonar

Tags: java

**Found a call to a method which will perform a byte to String (or String to byte) conversion, and will assume that the default platform encoding is suitable. This will cause the application behaviour to vary between platforms. Use an alternative API and specify a charset name or Charset object explicitly.**

```
try {           
 OutputStream outputStream = pResponse.getOutputStream();             
 if (ticketList != null && !ticketList.isEmpty()) {                    
    outputStream.write(ticketList.getBytes());                     
    outputStream.flush();                 
    outputStream.close();             
  }         
} catch (IOException e) {             
  Logger.logInfo(getClass(), "ticket list download", e);                 
  Logger.logError(getClass(), "ticket list download",    
     e.getMessage());        
 }
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly define what charset to use. Usually UTF-8 is a good bet.

```
try {
 Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");           
 OutputStream outputStream = pResponse.getOutputStream();             
 if (ticketList != null && !ticketList.isEmpty()) {                    
    outputStream.write(ticketList.getBytes(charset));                     
    outputStream.flush();                 
    outputStream.close();             
  }         
} catch (IOException e) {             
  Logger.logInfo(getClass(), "ticket list download", e);                 
  Logger.logError(getClass(), "ticket list download",    
     e.getMessage());        
 }
```